# problem when Filtering Table with custom DatePicker TableCell JavaFX

Tags: javafx, datepicker, tableview, tablecell

i'm trying to make custom table cell with a DatePicker. and having Filtered list in the table that filters the contents depending on radio button selection. when i select a date for a cell everything works fine.

Screenshot 1

[image: screenshot]

but when trying to filter and fire the predicate, the date looks going down to the bottom of the table. and when re-selecting the old radio button, it appears in the correct row.

Screenshot 2

[image: screenshot 2]

any Ideas?

my controller :

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<SetterGetter, String> colStatus;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<SetterGetter, Integer> colCode;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<SetterGetter, LocalDate> colDueDate;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<SetterGetter, String> colName;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton rdAll;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton rdDelayed;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton rdDone;

    @FXML
    private TableView<SetterGetter> tableTasks;

    private RadioButton selectedRadioButton;

    ObservableList<SetterGetter> mainTaskList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    FilteredList<SetterGetter> tableTaskList = new FilteredList<>(mainTaskList, p -> true);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        selectedRadioButton = rdAll;

        colCode.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SetterGetter, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SetterGetter, Integer> event) {
                SetterGetter row = event.getRowValue();
                row.setId(event.getNewValue());
            }
        });

        colName.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SetterGetter, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SetterGetter, String> event) {
                SetterGetter row = event.getRowValue();
                row.setName(event.getNewValue());
            }
        });

        colStatus.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SetterGetter, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SetterGetter, String> event) {
                SetterGetter row = event.getRowValue();
                row.setStatus(event.getNewValue().equals("منجز") ? 0 : 1);
            }
        });
        colCode.setCellValueFactory(b -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(b.getValue().getId()).asObject());
        colDueDate.setCellValueFactory(b -> b.getValue().getDate());
        colName.setCellValueFactory(b -> new SimpleStringProperty(b.getValue().getName()));
        colStatus.setCellValueFactory(b -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                b.getValue().getStatus() == 0 ? "منجز"
                        : "لم ينجز بعد")
        );

        colCode.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
        colName.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        colStatus.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "منجز",
                "لم ينجز بعد")
                )
        );
        colDueDate.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<SetterGetter, LocalDate>, TableCell<SetterGetter, LocalDate>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<SetterGetter, LocalDate> call(TableColumn<SetterGetter, LocalDate> setterGetterStringTableColumn) {
                return new DatePickerTableCell();
            }
        });

        mainTaskList.addAll(
                new SetterGetter(0, null, null, 1),
                new SetterGetter(1, null, null, 1)
        );

        tableTasks.setItems(tableTaskList);
    }

    @FXML
    void addCheck(ActionEvent event) {
        mainTaskList.add(new SetterGetter(0,
                null,
                null,
                0)
        );
    }

    @FXML
    void selectRadioButton(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() != selectedRadioButton) {
            RadioButton newRadio = (RadioButton) event.getSource();
            newRadio.setStyle("-fx-font-family:arial;-fx-font-size:14;-fx-font-weight:bold;-fx-border-color:red;-fx-border-radius:20;");
            selectedRadioButton.setStyle("-fx-font-family:arial;-fx-font-size:14;-fx-font-weight:bold;");
            selectedRadioButton = newRadio;
        }
        firePredicate();
    }

    private void firePredicate() {
        tableTaskList.setPredicate(p -> {
            if (selectedRadioButton.equals(rdDone) && p.getStatus() != 0)
                return false;
            else if (selectedRadioButton.equals(rdDelayed) && p.getStatus() != 1)
                return false;
            else return true;
        });
    }

}
```

DatePickerTableCell class:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class DatePickerTableCell extends TableCell<SetterGetter, LocalDate> {
    private final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

    public DatePickerTableCell() {

        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        setGraphic(datePicker);
        setText(null);
        datePicker.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                commitEdit(datePicker.getValue());
            }
        });
    }

     @Override
      public void commitEdit(LocalDate s) {
          super.commitEdit(s);
          setText(s.toString());
          setGraphic(null);
          setItem(s);
     }


    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText(datePicker.getValue() == null ? null : datePicker.getValue().toString());
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
```

SetterGetter class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class SetterGetter {
    int id;
    String name;
    ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date;
    int status;

    public SetterGetter(int id, String name, ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date, int status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Main class :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 565, 551));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="551.0" prefWidth="565.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tableTasks" editable="true" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="163.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="554.0" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 15;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0">
         <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="colDueDate" prefWidth="112" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 15;" text="التاريخ" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="colStatus" prefWidth="112" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 15;" text="الحالة" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="colName" prefWidth="112" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 15;" text="الأسم" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="colCode" prefWidth="112" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 15;" text="الكود" />
         </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="27.0" spacing="15.0">
         <children>
            <RadioButton fx:id="rdDelayed" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectRadioButton" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 14; -fx-font-weight: bold;" text="لم ينجز بعد">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
               <toggleGroup>
                  <ToggleGroup fx:id="radioGroup" />
               </toggleGroup>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="rdDone" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectRadioButton" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 14; -fx-font-weight: bold;" text="منجز" toggleGroup="$radioGroup">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="rdAll" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectRadioButton" selected="true" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 14; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-radius: 20 20 20 20;" text="الكل" toggleGroup="$radioGroup">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </RadioButton>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <Button layoutX="473.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addCheck" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="77.0" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 18;" text="إضافة">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Inline editing with custom cells is more complicated than non-editable tableviews.  Consider using a separate form for editing such as in the [makery tutorial](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/), rather than inline editing.  Of course, it depends on your requirements, perhaps inline editing will be better for your app if you can manage to implement it correctly.

Comment: btw: there is another error the cell implementation - it's adding a new action handler in every call of startEdit, they will accumulate. Better move the registration into the constructor.

Comment: @jewelsea really reluctant to spread the old example in the oracle tutorial - the whole editing section ... is .. not good enough, to put it mildly. Starting with forcing commitHandlers by suboptimal data api to suboptimal cell implementation. It never was optimal and didn't age well.

Comment: @kleopatra yep, understood, I removed the Oracle tutorial link.  My preferred solution is to skip inline editing in the TableViews wherever possible and edit the data in separate forms, similarly to advised in [eden coding's JavaFX MVC best practices](https://edencoding.com/mvc-in-javafx/#best-practices).

Comment: @jewelsea yet another basket of _best practices_ .. ;) In-table editing isn't wrong nor is it difficult in itself - it simply is buggy, though improving slowly (MS Access got it right as early as the end of last century, why-o-why can't java uis, *sigh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple things missing in your demo. Among that, one is already mentioned by @jewelsea in his comment.

**Issue#1:**

I noticed that you have not added a commit event for the date column. You need to persist the value(date) into the row object to get correct results when filtering.

Your code in the initialize method will be something like this:

```
colDueDate.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SetterGetter, LocalDate>>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SetterGetter, LocalDate> event) {
        SetterGetter row = event.getRowValue();
        if(row.date==null){
            row.setDate(new SimpleObjectProperty<>());
        }
        row.date.set(event.getNewValue());
    }
});
```

**Issue#2**:

As mentioned by @jewelsea, you need to override the updateItem() method of the TableCell when defining a custom cell. The code in the DatePickerTableCell will be like:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (isEditing()) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(datePicker);
    } else {
        setGraphic(null);
        if (item != null) {
            setText(item.toString());
        } else {
            setText(null);
        }
    }
}
```

The missing if-else condition in the updateItem is the main cause for your actual issue of the cell value to be in inappropriate place.

A VirtualFlow reuses the cells and can place it any where. It is our duty to ensure that it renders correctly when the updateItem is called. If the if-else condition is missing, you can see cell being used with wrong value.

**Issue#3**: *Not exactly an issue ;)*

Use proper naming conventions for the setter/getter of observable properties in the SetterGetter class.

```
public LocalDate getDate() {
    return date.get();
}

public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
    this.date.set(date);
}

public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateProperty() {
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Issue #3 is related to a larger "issue". The default `onEditCommit` event handler tries to set the `ObservableValue` returned by the `cellValueFactory` if it also implements `WritableValue`. If the OP had simply used JavaFX properties correctly from the start, none of those `onEditCommit` handlers would be necessary. Though that would also involve modifying the OP's code to do the "number to string" conversions in a custom cell rather than the value factory (which shouldn't be too hard with a `TextFieldTableCell` and a `StringConverter`).

Comment: the OP has two issues that are basically unrelated: a) the incorrect api in the data class b) the missing updateItem in the cell. _a_ forces commit handlers _b_ leads to the visual artefact when re-using the cell for an empty cell. In this answer, the solution for _a_ is incorrect, because it fiddles with data internals instead of using public api and the solution for _b_ looks a bit fishy because it should not be necessary to modify the cell layout in updateItem if it is correctly reset in start/cancel/commit (assuming a well-behaved super which might not be the case ;)

Comment: @jewelsea _updateItem needs to be a bit more sophisticated due to the editing capability_ not necessarily: if the editing components are added/removed correctly in the editing lifecycle methods the plain update as in the previous version of the answer should be good enough. I'm aware that the concrete implementations in the cell package are doing the state update in updateItem (probably due to a bag of bugs in editing life cycle, some of which were fixed recently) but consider that wrong (and makes is difficult to implement super correctly ;)

Comment: @Slaw arrgg .. you are right: forgot the implementation of the default commit handler .. was confused because the edited date wasn't saved - which is due to the initial (and also after editing) property is null, so nothing to save to. So even with the suboptimal api (_a_ in my first comment) we would _not_ need a commit handler if the date (the property) would have been initialized in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The base problem in the question is the visual artefact when hiding a data row that contains a value in the date column. The reason for that artefact is the missing override of `updateItem(S, boolean)` in the custom cell implementation which leads to incorrect cell state when that cell is re-used (as already noted in comments and [Sai's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72780742/203657) answer). The solution is to implement the method.

Hammering in: updateItem is specified in Cell and *none* of the direct descendants of IndexedCell - that is neither ListCell nor Tree-/TableCell nor TreeCell - override it to do anything useful. Which implies that each and every custom cell implementation extending those **has to** do it itself. The api doc *the updateItem method can be overridden to allow for complete customisation of the cell* is not quite correct.

Problem might be: how to override it correctly? Its purpose is to update the visual state of the cell based on the item. There are two basic rules:

- always call super *before* doing custom stuff
- whatever is set if there is an item must be reversed if there is none

Example:

```
protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty || item == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        setText(item.toString());
        setGraphic(getGraphic(item));
    }
}
```

Note: this is slightly different from the example in the api doc in actually setting an item-related graphic (without, resetting the graphic for the empty state doesn't make sense ;)

Next problem might be editing: typically, a cell meant for editing has an input control (f.i. a TextField) only while in editing mode. This implies showing/hiding those when toggling editing state. The responsibility for doing so resides in the edit lifecylce methods (start-/cancel-/commitEdit).

All applied to a custom DatePickerTableCell below:

- a DatePicker is the input control for editing and is set as the graphic
- editing is committed when receiving an action from the picker: note that the handler is set once in the constructor
- updateItem is implemented to configure both input control and text, independent of editing state
- the showing/hiding is controlled exclusively in the edit lifecycle methods by setting the cell's contentDisplay as needed; note that we back out off startEdit if super didn't switch into editing mode

Caveat: this strict separation of concerns (editing dependent visuals vs item dependent visuals) is possible since fx17 which fixes a bunch of bugs with cell editing state after cell re-use (see the [release notes](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/openjfx-17-release-notes/), f.i. [JDK-8264127](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8264127) for ListCell, [JDK-8265206](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8265206) for Tree-/TableCell, [JDK-8265210](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8265210) for TreeCell and related)

An alternative custom DatePickerTableCell:

```
public static class DatePickerTableCellEx1<S> extends TableCell<S, LocalDate> {
    private final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

    public DatePickerTableCellEx1() {
        datePicker.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                commitEdit(datePicker.getValue());
            }
        });
        setGraphic(datePicker);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            datePicker.setValue(null);
        } else {
            setText(datePicker.getConverter().toString(item));
            datePicker.setValue(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        if (!isEditing()) return;
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(LocalDate s) {
        super.commitEdit(s);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }
}
```

---

(Mostly unrelated) note on api design around Properties:

Typically, property valued fields should be not null and immutable

```
 // the field
 Property<Music> music; 

 // API
 Property<Music> gimmeTheMusic() {

 // usage
 Property<Music> music = radio.gimmeTheMusic();
 assertNotNull(music);
 music.addListener(...  // turn radio down/up);

 // __DO NOT__: it will break the usage
 void change(Property<Music> music) {
     this.music = music;
 }
```

With that in place, TableColumn's default commit handler will work as expected and there's no need to install a custom commit handler.